# Check/validate PDF files conformance to standards like PDF/A or PDF/UA

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, python, pdf

There are various PDF standards:

- PDF/A: PDF/A-1a, PDF/A-2a or PDF/A-3a
- PDF/UA
- potentially more

I want to check with Python if a given PDF file follows any of those.

I have seen [veraPDF](https://verapdf.org/) which seems to do what I need, but I have thousands of PDF files in a complex directory structure and I want to get statistics for a subset of those. Hence I want to perform this check with Python.

Answer (score 0):

[QuickPDF Library](https://www.debenu.com/blog/debenu-quick-pdf-library-11-15-released.html) from Foxit could do this, even the free Lite version.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it was not there when the question was asked, but veraPDF has a [command line interface](https://docs.verapdf.org/cli/):

> The veraPDF command line interface is the best way of processing batches of PDF files. It’s designed for integrating with scripted workflows, or for shell invocation from programs.

You could use any scripting language of your choosing to run veraPDF CLI and parse its output. The documentation has [examples on how to do validation](https://docs.verapdf.org/cli/validation/).